# Is there a keyboard shortkey to browse the history in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: command, history, jupyter

Is there an easy way to browse through command history and reuse old commands in a Jupyter notebook? Some equivalent to either the arrow up/down use in the iPython console or to the % sign use in Mathematica. 
(Although the answer might seem trivial to an expert, it is really hard to find for a newbie)

Comment: Looking through the shortcuts help (pressing `h` in command mode) as well as looking through commands in command palette - the answer seems to be no, unfortunatelly. Maybe open an issue on github? I also think it whould be nice to have such shortcut in the notebook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was looking for the same. But a year later, and after about 10 min of scouring the best I found ([link](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/IPython-User-retrieve-previous-commands-in-notebook-td4933555.html)) is this magic command: `%recall last` or `%recall <integer>`, which after execution copies a command from history into a new cell. Probably not quite what you had been looking - a tad too kludgy compared to arrow up/down. But a good option for cells with lots of text.